# Calling a function from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have javascript file in following directory

```
/static
       /handler.js
       /evercookie.js
       /jquery.js
```

All I want to do from handler.js function call a function in evercookie.js. for example
in `handler.js`

```
   var ec = new evercookie();
        cookiePresent = false
        ec.get(suggestion_id, function(value) { 
            alert("Cookie value is " + value);
            cookiePresent = true;
    });
    if (cookiePresent) {
            return;
        } else {
            ec.set(suggestion_id, "1");
            alert("cookie set for " + suggestion_id);
    }
```

where **evercookie()** is in `evercookie.js`

when I try this it fails saying `evercookie not found`

How shall I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the order of your scripts is correct - `evercookie.js` needs to be referenced before any other script can use it.

**From:**

```
   /handler.js
   /evercookie.js
   /jquery.js
```

**To:**

```
   /jquery.js
   /evercookie.js
   /handler.js
```

The browser parses and interprets `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` ***top-down*** so if you try to access a property or instantiate an object that doesn't exist the browser will error...

*More on Browser Parsing:*

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#overview-of-the-parsing-model

Comment: Xander what does that mean and how it affects?

Answer (score 1):

You have to either just put the evercookie.js code above the code in your handler.js file, or you have to link to evercookie.js BEFORE you link to handler.js.

```
<script src="static/evercookie.js">
<script src="static/handler.js">
```